# Triggers in Parse Server using Swift

Tags: swift, triggers, digital-ocean, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

Recently, I was tasked to do a simple chat app for iOS, using Swift.. So, I have a parse server ready and running! All I want to know, is how to use triggers..

Let's say I have opened a conversation and I just received a new message. How can I get it, without constantly checking for new messages? I saw that cloud code is probably the way to go, but if it is so, is it practical? I mean, if I have 5000 users and they are constantly chatting, will it perform well?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Parse LiveQuery](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX) component.

1. [Add Live Query to your server's config](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-LiveQuery#server-setup):

   ```
   let api = new ParseServer({
     ...,
     liveQuery: {
       classNames: ['Test', 'TestAgain']
     }
   });

   // Initialize a LiveQuery server instance, app is the express app of your Parse Server
   let httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
   httpServer.listen(port);
   var parseLiveQueryServer = ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
   ```
2. Install Parse LiveQuery library as a pod to your project (`pod 'ParseLiveQuery'`).
3. Subscribe for events:

   ```
   let myQuery = Message.query()!.where("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
   let subscription: Subscription<Message> = myQuery.subscribe()
   ```
4. Handle events:

   ```
   subscription.handleEvent { query, event in
       // Handle event
       // This callback gets called every time an object is created, updated, deleted etc.
   }
   ```

Comment: I already tried them, but I couldn't get them to work! The events don't respond at all.. I think it's very soon for public use..

Comment: I use it for my project, it works fine. If you have a trouble with Parse LiveQuery, post another question related to it. But your current question can be solved by Parse LiveQuery. This is what it's supposed for.

Comment: Ok.. By the way, putting Live Queries aside, can my issue be achieved by cloud code?

Comment: So, I tried LiveQueries for once more and they finally worked!!! They seem like a good solution, although I noticed some problems... (like pointers comparison) Anyway, how efficient would you say they are? I mean, in a dual core, 2GB ram machine, how many users would you estimate it can support?

Comment: @SotirisKaniras no idea, my app is not in production yet.

Comment: @SotirisKaniras if my answer helped you, please mark it as answer.